# Implement ink annotations on iOS 11 PDFKit document

Tags: ios, pdf, touch, ios11

I want to allow the user to draw on an iOS 11 PDFKit document viewed in a PDFView. The drawing should ultimately be embedded inside the PDF.

The latter I have solved by adding a PDFAnnotation of type "ink" to the PDFPage with a UIBezierPath corresponding to the user's drawing.

However, how do I actually record the touches the user makes on top of the PDFView to create such an UIBezierPath?

I have tried overriding touchesBegan on the PDFView and on the PDFPage, but it is never called. I have tried adding a UIGestureRecognizer, but didn't accomplish anything.

I'm assuming that I need to afterwards use the PDFView instance method convert(_ point: CGPoint, to page: PDFPage) to convert the coordinates obtained to PDF coordinates suitable for the annotation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by creating a PDFViewController class extending UIViewController and UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. I added a PDFView as a subview, and a UIBarButtonItem to the navigationItem, that serves to toggle annotation mode.

I record the touches in a UIBezierPath called signingPath, and have the current annotation in currentAnnotation of type PDFAnnotation using the following code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: pdfView)
        signingPath = UIBezierPath()
        signingPath.move(to: pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!))
        annotationAdded = false
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 800, height: 600))
        lastPoint = pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: pdfView)
        let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!)
        let page = pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!
        signingPath.addLine(to: convertedPoint)
        let rect = signingPath.bounds

        if( annotationAdded ) {
            pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.removeAnnotation(currentAnnotation)
            currentAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)

            var signingPathCentered = UIBezierPath()
            signingPathCentered.cgPath = signingPath.cgPath
            signingPathCentered.moveCenter(to: rect.center)
            currentAnnotation.add(signingPathCentered)
            pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(currentAnnotation)

        } else {
            lastPoint = pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!)
            annotationAdded = true
            currentAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
            currentAnnotation.add(signingPath)
            pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(currentAnnotation)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: pdfView)
        signingPath.addLine(to: pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!))

        pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.removeAnnotation(currentAnnotation)

        let rect = signingPath.bounds
        let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
        annotation.color = UIColor(hex: 0x284283)
        signingPath.moveCenter(to: rect.center)
        annotation.add(signingPath)
        pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

The annotation toggle button just runs:

```
pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled = !pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled
```

This was really the key to it, as this disables scrolling on the PDF and enables me to receive the touch events.

The way the touch events are recorded and converted into PDFAnnotation immediately means that the annotation is visible while writing on the PDF, and that it is finally recorded into the correct position in the PDF - no matter the scroll position.

Making sure it ends up on the right page is just a matter of similarly changing the hardcoded 0 for page number to the pdfView.page(for: position, nearest:true) value.

Comment: Not sure that the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 800, height: 600))` is doing in this code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't prepare the code for posting here - I felt I had to put up my code now that other people were interested, so the example does potentially contains code that is not required for the example here, but was in there for other purposes for my app (which is still unfinished). As far as I remember that line of code was there because other I received warnings that no context had been started.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood me, it was not a negative review, It was intended as a question. I wondered why it was required, what purpose it served.

I did my own little UIGestureRecognizer for a PDFView, and I can confirm that it will work without it (did not see a warning on the simulator. Perhaps on a device, it is different)

Comment: As far as I remember it wasn't the UIGestureRecognizer code that required it, but rather when I wanted to actually draw the annotation on the document while the user is drawing/writing on the iPad. I have been testing with a real device and the Apple Pencil - works quite well!

Comment: moveCenter is occured error in swift4. How Can I do?

Comment: @You.Brighton Best to open a new question asking about that.

Answer (score 5):

I've done this by creating a new view class (eg Annotate View) and putting on top of the PDFView when the user is annotating.

This view uses it's default touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded methods to create a bezier path following the gesture. Once the touch has ended, my view then saves it as an annotation on the pdf.

Note: you would need a way for the user to decide if they were in an annotating state.

**For my main class**

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, PDFViewDelegate, VCDelegate {

var pdfView: PDFView?
var touchView: AnnotateView?

override func loadView() {
   touchView = AnnotateView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 600))
   touchView?.backgroundColor = .clear
   touchView?.delegate = self
   view.addSubview(touchView!)
}

 func addAnnotation(_ annotation: PDFAnnotation) {
    print("Anotation added")
    pdfView?.document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
}
```

**My annotation view**

```
class AnnotateView: UIView {
var path: UIBezierPath?
var delegate: VCDelegate?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Initialize a new path for the user gesture
    path = UIBezierPath()
    path?.lineWidth = 4.0

    var touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    path?.move(to: touch.location(in: self))
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Add new points to the path
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first! 
    path?.addLine(to: touch.location(in: self))
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first 
    path?.addLine(to: touch!.location(in: self))
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: self.bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
    annotation.add(self.path!)
    delegate?.addAnnotation(annotation)
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Draw the path
    path?.stroke()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that - I had already created a solution which didn't require adding a view on top. Your solution is less desirable because it means that the PDF must be single page and cannot be scrolled - otherwise the annotation will appear in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

jksoegaard's answer, while being the inspiration to all of my work on this matter, has a flaw: during touchedMoved, multiple PDF annotations are created, and consequently the PDF page becomes bogged down with annotations, which affects its loading time severely. I wrote code that draws on a CAShapeLayer during the touchedMoved phase, and creates the completed PDF annotation only in the touchesEnded phase.

My implementation is a subclass of UIGestureRecognizer, and it allows you to choose between pen, highlighter and eraser, and choose color and width. It also includes an undo manager. The example project is [here](https://github.com/ClassicalDude/pdfView-Freedraw).

**Original Answer**

Adding to jksoegaard's excellent answer, a few clarifications for newbies like myself:

1. You need to include UIBezierPath+.swift in your project for .moveCenter and rect.center to be recognized. Download from https://github.com/xhamr/paintcode-path-scale.
2. These lines can be excluded:

   ```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 800, height: 600))
   ```

and

```
    let page = pdfView.page(for: position, nearest: true)!
```

3. You need to declare a few global vars outside the functions:

   ```
    var signingPath = UIBezierPath()
    var annotationAdded : Bool?
    var lastPoint : CGPoint?
    var currentAnnotation : PDFAnnotation?
   ```
4. Finally, if you want the ink to be wider and nicely colored, you need to do two things:

a. Every time before you see annotation.add or currentAnnotation.add, you need (use annotation or currentAnnotation as needed by that function):

```
    let b = PDFBorder()
    b.lineWidth = { choose a pixel number here }
    currentAnnotation?.border = b
    currentAnnotation?.color=UIColor.{ your color of choosing }
```

I recommend specifying a low alpha for the color. The result is beautiful, and affected by the speed of your stroke. For example, red would be:

```
    UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 0.1)
```

b. The rect in which every touch is recorded needs to accommodate for the thicker lines. Instead of

```
    let rect = signingPath.bounds
```

Try, for an example of 10px of thickness:

```
    let rect = CGRect(x:signingPath.bounds.minX-5, 
    y:signingPath.bounds.minY-5, width:signingPath.bounds.maxX- 
    signingPath.bounds.minX+10, height:signingPath.bounds.maxY- 
    signingPath.bounds.minY+10)
```

**IMPORTANT**: The touchesEnded function also makes use of the currentAnnotation variable. You must repeat the definition of rect within that function as well (either the short one or my suggested one above), and repeat the definition of currentAnnotation there as well:

```
    currentAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
```

If you don't, a single tap that did not move will make your app crash.

I can verify that once the file is saved, the annotations are retained. Sample code for saving:

```
    let pdfData = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation()
    let annotatedPdfUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\ 
    (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentsDirectory, .userDomainMask, 
        true)[0])/AnnotatedPDF.pdf")
    try! pdfData!.write(to: annotatedPdfUrl)
```

Comment: If anybody still need to solve this task, I created a complete tutorial: https://medium.com/@artempoluektov/ios-pdfkit-ink-annotations-tutorial-4ba19b474dce

Comment: @zramled - please see the edit at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Hey Ron, Thanks for the project although the performance has significantly improved but still I see a lot of lag while zooming the pdf, are there any more tricks or techniques to overcome this memory issue. I critically need to over come this particular issue because of my company requirements. This issue becomes worse when I use ipads instead of pro's......Thanks.

Comment: Dear Raj, just following up for the sake of whoever happens to read your comment - we discussed it here: https://github.com/ClassicalDude/pdfView-Freedraw/issues/3.

TL;DR: the problem is with PDFKit, not with the framework. Heavily annotated PDFs, when rendered by PDFKit, are sluggish and take a lot of memory. My framework is intended for a light load of annotations. If a developer absolutely needs to be able to work with heavily annotated PDFs, I recommend keeping the annotations as CAShapeLayers until you save and close the document, and commit the annotations to the PDF only then.