# How to use pencil (e.g. ink) annotation and finger touch navigation in PDFKit concurrently on iOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdfview

I wrote a PDF annotation App in Swift with PDFKit that uses touchesBegan/Moved/Ended to make annotations on a PDF. Works perfect for drawing annotations.

In order to get the pencil touch events I needed to make a toggle button to set "isUserInteractionEnabled = false" on the PDFView if I do annotations and set "isUserInteractionEnabled = true" to navigate (pan/zoom) the PDF document.
With "isUserInteraction = true" all the touch event are "eaten" by the PDFView (I think it's the documentView Scrollview) and are never called on the ViewController.

The pepetual switching is really annoying for the user and not usable.

So how do I use the touchesBegan/Moved/Ended overrides in the ViewController and being able to navigate (pan/zoom) in the PDF with finger touches without toggling isUserInteractionEnabled all the time?

The App should run on iPad with pencil only.

Thanks for taking your time,
Lars

Sample implementation to make things clearer:
(inside class ViewController: UIViewController)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pdfView = PDFView()

    pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pdfView)

    pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestPDF", withExtension: "pdf")!
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)

    pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //touches events are called ... annotation with pencil mode
    //pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //touches events are NEVER called ... but pan/zoom works
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesBegan called!")

    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.type == .stylus {
            print("touchesBegan pencil annotation ...")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesMoved called!")

    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.type == .stylus {
            print("touchesMoved pencil annotation ...")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesEnded called!")

    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.type == .stylus {
            print("touchesEnded pencil annotation ...")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your implementation ?

Comment: sure ... I edited my original post. The sample implementation is based on a new iOS->Single View App project using xcode 9.

Comment: How did you implement InkAnnotation in PDFView ? i'm having problem on implementing this, can you please tell me ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48432320/9703929 ... this idea is what I use for all of my drawing code including ink annotation

Comment: is it solved???

Comment: After spending a lot of time, I solved this case and created this complete guide: https://medium.com/@artempoluektov/ios-pdfkit-ink-annotations-tutorial-4ba19b474dce

Answer (score 2):

You can implement all your drawing operations in PDFView's UIGestureRecognizer and implement this method also.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    if touch.type == .stylus
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I subclassed PDFView and have overridden gestureRecognizer with you code fragment ... and I can get the first touch (start) with the pencil.
But for the drawing code I need (1) the start, (2) the movement and (3) ending point of the pencil stroke - I can see no way doing this with gestureRecognizer.

Comment: And the PDF moves while using the pencil which is not useful ;-)
It would be so easy if I could prevent PDFView from using the pencil at all ... I don't need scrolling with the pencil.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but I'd just found myself in the exact same situation. So, I found this Apple's sample code: [Leveraging Touch Input for Drawing Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/leveraging_touch_input_for_drawing_apps)!
And ended up with creating custom gesture recognizer. It's still very alpha code, but you would understand the idea:

```
class PDFDrawingGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
weak var pdfView: PDFView!
private var lastPoint = CGPoint()
private var currentAnnotation : PDFAnnotation?


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first,
        let numberOfTouches = event?.allTouches?.count,
        numberOfTouches == 1 {
        state = .began

        let position = touch.location(in: pdfView)
        let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.currentPage!)

        lastPoint = convertedPoint
    } else {
        state = .failed
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    state = .changed

    guard let position = touches.first?.location(in: pdfView) else { return }
    let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.currentPage!)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: lastPoint)
    path.addLine(to: convertedPoint)
    lastPoint = convertedPoint

    if currentAnnotation == nil {
        let border = PDFBorder()
        border.lineWidth = 10
        border.style = .solid

        currentAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: pdfView.bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: [
            PDFAnnotationKey.border: border,
            PDFAnnotationKey.color: UIColor.red,
            PDFAnnotationKey.interiorColor: UIColor.red,
            ])
        let pageIndex = pdfView.document!.index(for: pdfView.currentPage!)
        pdfView.document?.page(at: pageIndex)?.addAnnotation(currentAnnotation!)
    }
    currentAnnotation!.add(path)


}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let position = touches.first?.location(in: pdfView) else {
        state = .ended
        return
    }

    let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(position, to: pdfView.currentPage!)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: lastPoint)
    path.addLine(to: convertedPoint)

    currentAnnotation?.add(path)
    currentAnnotation = nil

    state = .ended
}
}
```

Finally, add this gesture recognizer to your PDFView. If you want your gesture recognizer to work only with pencil, in `touchesBegan` method check your touch origin.